# How do I expand 3 dots in selector in selenium stack trace

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, stack-trace

Is there a way to expand 3 dots and see full selector in the selenium stacktrace on element click intercepted error? Without it, it is really hard to understand what is blocking the click.

Maybe I need to hardcode output in my code, or change selenium settings somehow?
[pycharm screenshot of the 3 dots mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhBPi.png)

Comment: well you can see is div with data-v-bebe40fe="" and class="banner". Can you see the driver working? problaby is a cookie to acept/reject banner

Comment: There is more than 200 elements found on a page wit this. I really need a full selector, and selenium has it, I just do not know how to make it show it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error stack trace:

[image: error]

it clearly states the `<span>` element:

```
<span data-v-bbda84b0="">...</span>
```

isn't clickable. The click is obscured by the `<div>` element:

```
<div data-v-bbda40fe="" class="banner">...</div>
```

the banner element, most possibly the *Accept* / *Reject* [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) banner.

---

### Solution

To identify and highlight the element in *DevTools* you can use:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  div.banner
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='banner']
  ```

---

### Conclusion

Before you start interacting with the webapplication it is mandatory to comply with the site cookie settings. So you need to accept/deny the cookie conscent first.

Comment: There is no accept/deny cookies banner. 
Is there a way to get full selector without 3 dots from selenium?

Comment: My question is not about this particluar case. I have solved it, and the problem was in other thing. 
My question is about extending selenium stacktrace report, so in the future I will have complete selector of the element that is blocking my action.